# How to keep a value encoded using URL encoding when receiving it in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, aes, quarkus, urlencode

Good afternoon, I am currently working with Apache Camel in Quarkus and I am working with an API that has the following url structure:

```
https://ip:port/userProfile/v3/users/{user_id}
```

The **user_id** is a value that must be encrypted, in this case AES encryption was used, which uses special characters, example of AES encryption:

```
RIF-J756621232 --> WKqxB/qNPQUz6wRbHZrpBQ==
```

Example above when encrypting the value RIF-J756621232, the encryption described above is obtained, the issue is that when passing this encrypted value in the mentioned url I get an error due to the special characters that are sent, when sending in the URL:

```
https://ip:port/userProfile/v3/users/WKqxB/qNPQUz6wRbHZrpBQ==  --> Not Working'
```

So what I did was apply a url encoding, leaving the url to send as follows:

```
https://ip:port/userProfile/v3/users/WKqxB%2FqNPQUz6wRbHZrpBQ%3D%3D --> Working'
```

The problem that happens is the following, this userId value is sent by a client that obtains it from a system unknown to me, in turn this unknown system receives it from another service called **NewUserId**, this **NewUserId** should send the value of the **user_id** encrypted with AES and in turn with url encoding, the main idea of ​​all this is that the client does not have to apply the encoding so that it can pass through the url, it is a transparent step for it, what is happening is that upon receiving the value in my **UserProfile** service (the one with the URL), the user_id value is automatically decoded using URL decoding and the value is returned in AES encryption, which I wouldn't like, I would like the received value to persist with the AES encryption and URL encoding to be synchronized with the external client, the main idea is to keep the value **WKqxB%2FqNPQUz6wRbHZrpBQ%3D%3D**, however, I am seeing that Apache Camel is decoding the url value defautl, it is possible to change this configuration?

Comment: Take a look at RAW
https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html#HowdoIconfigureendpoints-Configuringparametervaluesusingrawvalues